# Android Studio dosn't show a folder in the project window tree

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, directory, project-structure

I try to create simple folder. I can see it is created on disk, but I can't see it in the project display. I did all the synch and reload from disk things:

[image]

And the *jni* directory exists on disk:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are seeing Android-related files. You can change that by clicking on *Android* (on top of the files tree, in your first screenshot) and selecting *Project*.