# How to add template directory in django?

Tags: python, django

I'm getting `TemplateDoesNotExist at /task/` error.

This is my folder structure for project:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zMG2.png]

**This is my taskmate/urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('task/',include('todolist_app.urls')),
    path('todolist/',include('todolist_app.urls')),
]
```

**This is my todolist_app/urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
#from todolist_app import views
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.todolist, name='todolist'),
]
```

**This is my todolist_app/views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def todolist(request):
    return render(request, 'todolist.html',{})
```

**This is my settings.py(important components)**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),'todolist_app/templates').replace('\\','/'))],#'DIRS': 
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I'm highly suspicious that the issue I'm getting is due to "DIRS" of template. I have tried couple of different things there, but none seem to have worked.

These are what I've tried there:

```
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'templates').replace('\\','/')],#'DIRS': 
    'DIRS': [(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),'todolist_app/templates').replace('\\','/'))],#'DIRS':
```

I've also added "todolist_app" to installed apps.

Comment: Simply add this `'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],`

Comment: Can you share the project structure in the site itself by editing the question? Its not clear there. Also can you share the error traceback?

Comment: 'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str' 'This error comes when I do what Sunderam Dubey said in first comment.

Comment: https://dpaste.com/B92G6JT8J Heres the traceback with the         'DIRS': [(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(_ _file_ _)),'todolist_app/templates').replace('\\','/'))],#'DIRS':

Comment: You need to give appname if thery is any.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django TemplateDoesNotExist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926049/django-templatedoesnotexist)

Comment: @SunderamDubey I've tried all steps given there. But still failing.

Comment: At last, you should restart server in another port  using `python manage.py runserver 500` if then also it not solves the problem, then the last option is you can share GitHub repo, I'll see it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add app_name to your html. This might solve the issue

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def todolist(request):
    return render(request, 'app_name/todolist.html',{})
```

## Update:

make sure your settings.py TEMPLATE section is configured as below:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: I tried it. It didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: @pieszen06 Can you share project structure in a tabular form in the question itself?

Comment: @SunderamDubey how do I do it? is there a tool/cmd for it?

Comment: @SS_SS This is only relevant when the person makes templates folder inside apps itself, currently we don't know this thing, that's why I am asking for project strucutre.

Comment: @pieszen06  You can share project structure as show in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73670772) question.

Comment: @SunderamDubey I see it has it within app folder. Check the hyperlink above in problem statement.

Comment: @SunderamDubey I added the project structure from VS code.

Comment: @SS_SS I did exactly like you said in your update and still it's not working. Same error.

Comment: @pieszen06, I see you have two include urls in your project urls.py. you need to have only one. Sort this and check out again...

Comment: hmm did it. @SS_SS but not fixed yet.

Comment: @pieszen06 Does the server automatically reloading after save or not in other files?

Comment: @SunderamDubey I restarted laptop to check, it still doesn't work. Same error.

Comment: @SS_SS it's been fixed. I did what you said here. Plus this 1/n

Comment: >the problem here is that templates are not just in templates, they are in `templates/html`. Either remove that extra level, or use "html/todolist.html" in your render call. 

I added html/todolist.html in my render call. n/n

Answer (score 0):

What fixed the issue was just add html/todolist.html in render. i.e this in views.py of todolist_app:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def todolist(request):
    return render(request, 'html/todolist.html',{})
```

This is not my solution.